# grep match only lines in a specified range

Tags: linux, grep

Is it possible to use grep to match only lines with numbers in a pre-specified range?
For instance I want to list all lines with numbers in the range `[1024, 2048]` of a log that contain the word 'error'.

I would like to keep the '-n' functionality i.e. have the number of the matched line in the file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sed -n '1024,2048{/error/{=;p}}' | paste - -
```

Here `/error/` is a pattern to match and `=` prints the line number.

Comment: I accept your answer because it also prints the original line numbers. I do not quite understand the bit with {/error/{=;p}} could you explain that please?

Comment: /error/ is the pattern to be matched within the range of number given.

Answer (score 8):

Use sed first:

> sed -ne '1024,2048p'  | grep ...

-n says don't print lines, 'x,y,p' says print lines x-y inclusive (overrides the -n)

Comment: The reason I believe Prince John Wesley's solution is better is that it also prints the original line numbers, while here I will have their number in the specified range. Still +1.

Comment: @John3136 what is the difference between `-n` and `ne`?

Comment: @ManuelJordan -e just says "an expression follows". You don't really need it but I just do it out of habit - some versions of sed may be more picky than others and want -e. If -n works for you then no harm using it,.

Answer (score 3):

`Awk` is a good tool for the job:

```
$ awk 'NR>=1024 && NR<=2048 && /error/ {print NR,$0}' file
```

In `awk` the variable `NR` contains the current line number and `$0` contains the line itself.

The benefits with using `awk` is that you can easily change the output to display however you want it. For instance to separate the line number from line with a colon followed by a TAB:

```
$ awk 'NR>=1024 && NR<=2048 && /error/ {print NR,$0}' OFS=':\t' file
```